# DisplayName attribute is ignored while json conversion

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class as below

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    [DisplayName ("Please Enter Your Age")]       
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }        
}
```

I serialized this object to Json using `json()` of MVC3, but the `DisplayName` attribute is ignored. I get the json as

```
"*{"Name":"Person Name","**Age**":28,"Sex":"Male"}*"
```

Actually i was expecting

```
"*{"Name":"Person Name","**Please Enter Your Age**":28,"Sex":"Male"}*"
```

Code converts the object to json

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult JsonTest()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Age = 28;
    person.Name = "Person Name";
    person.Sex = "Male";        
    return (Json(person, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to give different names to your properties by using the `[DataMember(Name = "myOwnName")]` data annotation. Or write your own serializer.

Example can be found [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Internally the Json method uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to serialize the class into a JSON string. It doesn't allow you to change property names. I guess you will have to roll your own JSON serialization routine. The question is: why do you need that?

Comment: This is for a multi tenant application, where the property name is shown differently to different user(but same language). For e.g. User 1 see age as "Your Age" and user 2 see age as "Enter Your Age", etc..