# Display name of a property not working

Tags: c#

I have C# class as follows:

```
    public class Aps
    {
      [DisplayName("content-available")]
      public string contentavailable { get; set; }
      public string alert { get; set; }
      public string fetchKey { get; set; }
    }
```

I am serializing the class to JSON output, but the property name of contentavailable is not shown as content-available? Any ideas what i am doing incorrectly?

Comment: How are you serialising to JSON?

Comment: Refer this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289260/displayname-attribute-is-ignored-while-json-conversion

Comment: Serializing like this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y), where y is the object Aps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Newtonsoft.Json then you have to use the `JsonProperty` attribute, for example

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "my-id")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much.